# DIY ultrasonic sensor questions

Tags: ltspice

I am making a 40 kHz ultrasonic sensor. I need to detect when a person is at least 5 feet in front of an object. The sensor does not have to be extremely accurate. I am an electrical engineering student and have not had a lot of hands-on experience, but I am trying to learn. I found some schematics online for the transmitter and receiver pictured below. I also attached a link to the design I am trying to implement.
I will be most likely using an STM32 or an ESP32 for the MCU. I am trying to simulate the transmitter schematic in LTspice to understand how this works but I am not sure which part to test and what component to use for the part circled in red. Also in LTspice instead of Arduino pin 10 should I generate a 40 kHz square wave. I also have added a photo of my Ltspice diagram so far. I would appreciate any help!

http://www.kerrywong.com/2011/01/22/a-sensitive-diy-ultrasonic-range-sensor/

[image: Transmitter]

[image: LTspice]

[image]

Comment: Can you see how this circuit shorts out the supply during transitions?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 No I can't. What is causing that?

Comment: @PeteW Are you referring to the circuit diagram from the website or the LTspice diagram?

Comment: re: short out - also will pull a good amount of current when MCU is reset / power off (and its output pin is hiZ)

Comment: both. there may be a mistake in the transistor configuration // the comments in the blog post you link mention it

Comment: @PeteW If you look at the link the person was able to use that transmitter circuit diagram successfully. I am not sure what part of it is causing the short.

Comment: disconnect the input (or don't, either way) and run the simulation ...

Comment: @PeteW I updated my post with a picture of the output I am getting on nodes 1 and 2.

Comment: Take a look at collector current with rated nF of piezo then you will see what I meant with shootthru and capacitive load. You may want   Or need Dead time in crossover to be > rise time and low impedance switch

Comment: The common collector driver has output impedance at Vce(sat) ~ reduces towards Rb/hFE but hFE drops rapidly at Vce=1V  thus risetime is slow and shootthru is sustained and Pd rises rapidly

Answer (score 3):

The transmitter (what you are showing) is the easy part. The part you have circled in red is the transducer. It is a piezoelectric disk, typically in a tuned cavity that resonates at some particular frequency such as 40kHz. [Here](https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/cusa-t75-18-2400-th.pdf) is a datasheet of one such device (optimized for 40kHz). Electrically, it represents a capacitive load, plus it generates some voltage by itself once it starts moving. You can try simulating it with a capacitor of a few nF and see if the driver at least gets to +/-V close to the supply voltage within the half period of the transmitter waveform.

Rather than use that driver circuit, I suggest using a MOSFET gate driver chip such as the [MCP14A0155](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005470B.pdf).

The mechanical Q of the transmitter and receiver transducers have a great deal of effect on the behavior if you're intending on sending a sharp beep out and hoping to receive something relatively sharp. It will also be affected by the drive circuit. The transmitter datasheet, such as it is, is a bit sketchy on such matters.